# What episodes did Teselecta Appear in?

Tags: doctor-who

I have been wondering about a list of episodes that Teselecta appeared in, can I have a list of the episodes? I have not found any other places with useful information in one place.

Comment: http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Teselecta

Comment: Thank You, my google was not working well and only a few results came up, restart my computer, and it's fixed.

Comment: If you're looking for something beyond what is provided by the link Richard provides, please edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Doctor Who wikia article about the [Teselecta](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Teselecta), it has appeared in three episodes;

- [The Impossible Astronaut](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Impossible_Astronaut)
- [Let's Kill Hitler](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Let%27s_Kill_Hitler)
- [The Wedding of River Song](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wedding_of_River_Song)

Comment: Who could possibly want to downvote this?